# How to set vscode to show modified files in git repo automatically without refresh?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode on Mac OS, usually when the project is a git repository, whenever I modify something the editor will show the file modified with the corresponding color and letter in the project tree automatically.

However I formatted my Mac, installed vscode and this feature wasn't  available anymore, I have to manually click the refresh button in the Source Control tab in order to see the modified files.

When I press the refresh button the following output is shown in the output tab:

```
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git show :src/index.ts
> git check-ignore -z --stdin
```

I don't know if that helps discovering the problem.

I have vscode version `1.31.0` and Mac OS Mojave version `10.14.3`.

Any ideas to solve this ? and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the name of one of the folders I have in the path to my local repository, its name was `Hàdēs` which it wasn't read by the git command that vscode was trying to run.

So when I modify it to `Hades` without these accent, problem solved !

Now vscode is reading the changes and showing them normally :(

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could try `command + shift + p` and open `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

If you scroll down to the *git* panel make sure `git.autorefresh` is set to `true`

Comment: I've set `git.autorefresh` to `true`, but it still the same.. I think `true` is the default value for it.